# Why my jquery custom content scroller freezes in mozilla firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

Hi hello i'm practically new in jquery and recently having a problem regarding cross browser.When i tried on mozilla firefox after the editing , the jquery custom content scrollbar freezes my div rendering it unscrollable. Is there something wrong? it works before like a charm on mozilla firefox before i put flow slider.Even i remove the flowslider function, it's still freezes. In chrome everything works fine.

I know probably this is because my nooby mistake.Is there anything i can do to fix it? or probably someone help me fix the code?

Here are my javascript code:

```
$(function() {
          jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $(".slider-horizontal").FlowSlider({
                infinite: true,
                animation: "Accelerating",
                controllers: ["HoverCenter"],
                controllerOptions: [{
                    center: 100,
                    mouseStart: 300,
                    mouseEnd: 100
                }]
            }); 
        });
$(window).load(function() {
  $("#newboxes5, .gallery_container").mCustomScrollbar({
  advanced: {
updateOnContentResize: true
}
});

$(".gallery_container").mCustomScrollbar({
    horizontalScroll:true
});

$("#newboxes5").mCustomScrollbar("update");
});

});

        function slideSwitch() {
        var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');

        if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow IMG:last');

        var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
            : $('#slideshow IMG:first');

        $active.addClass('last-active');

        $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
            .addClass('active')
            .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1500, function() {
                $active.removeClass('active last-active');
            });
        }

        $(function() {
            setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 3000 );
        });
        function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
     $('.newboxes, .gallery_box').each(function(index) {
          if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
               $(this).show(200);
          }
          else {
               $(this).hide(200);
          }
     });

}
```

Comment: Are you spitting out any console errors?

Comment: I did check using firebug but there's none..the cycle works but the scroll freezes my div and i can't click on it.

Comment: can you throw the example in jsfiddle.net

Comment: i'm sorry i can't since i'm using made plugins jquery and since i'm a noob i can't recreate it on jsfiddle : (

Comment: Finally i got it fixed.

It freezes the jquery and the div's because mozzila interpret the negative value from z-index.